# _tkinter.TclError: can't find package tkdnd when running python script after using pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I made a program that I need to distribute to people who don't have python on their machines. Therefore, I used pyinstaller to make a .exe of it. The installing process goes fine but when running the .exe from command line I get the following error:

```
\VS Code Projects\Release Program\dist\release_script>release_script Traceback (most recent call last):   File "release_script.py", line 8, in <module>   File "tkinterDnD\tk.py", line 36, in __init__   File "tkinterDnD\tk.py", line 28, in _init_tkdnd
_tkinter.TclError: can't find package tkdnd [18012] Failed to execute script 'release_script' due to unhandled exception!
```

Here are my installed pip packages:[pip packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtVtx.png)

When combing through google I tried the following things.

1. pip install tkinterdnd2
2. copied tkdnd folder into the projects tlc folder [tkdnd folder in project folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCiQl.png)
3. copied the tkdnd folder into Python's tlc folder[tkdnd in python path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiVL7.png)
4. downloaded hook-tkinterdnd2.py, copied it next to the .py file that I'm using pyinstaller on and tried running this in cmd: python -m PyInstaller -F release_script.py --additional-hooks-dir=.

Maybe there was a 5th attempt but they all blend together by now. None of these attempts fixed the issue.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that PyInstaller includes the tkdnd package when you use it to make the executable. This makes sure that the application comes with all the files it needs.

```
pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import=tkdnd release_script.py
```

Run the above this makes sure that PyInstaller adds the tkdnd package to the program that is packaged.